# Use HttpURLConnection & AsyncTask on Android

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

I am discovering how to make HTTP requests in an Android application, so the first thing I tried to do is to test if the given url exists. I just want it to show "Webpage exists" if it exists and "Webpage do not exists" if it do not exists. But nothing is showing. There must be an error in my code, but I couldn't find it. So here is the code :

```
package com.nounoursheureux.excalicubeforum;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    private TextView text;
    private URL url;
    private Boolean result;
    private HttpTask httpTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = new TextView(this);
        httpTask = new HttpTask();
        httpTask.execute();
    }


    final class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

        private HttpURLConnection connection;
        private URL url;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.excalicube.net/");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) {
                    text.setText("La page existe");
                    return true;
                }
                else if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND ) {
                    text.setText("La page n'existe pas");
                    return false;           
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So I want the TextView to show the answer, but it stays empty 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to make a `HTTP request` in order to know whether an URL exists or not. From your code I'd say you're just opening the socket, which will always happen if the IP address exists. I'd suggest making a POST/GET request and see the result code.

This would be an example:

```
HttpGet req = new HttpGet(yourURL);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(req);

int resultCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line

```
text.setText("La page existe");
text.setText("La page n'existe pas");
```

You can not interact with UI inside doInBackground method. You should do all UI related work inside onPostExecute method.

If this solve your problem accept as answer.

Cheers...!